# How best to split strings in tibble and keep only the item that matches a desired string in dplyr/R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr

I'm processing someone else's data and they have a column of various genes and protein changes within those genes. I only care about one gene and wish to extract the protein changes (the numbers in this example). I've arrived at a solution that's inelegant and was hoping you all might have a better idea using `purrr` or something similar.

The string I want can be alone or at the beginning/middle/end of multiple entries separated by semicolons. I would prefer a solution that is tolerant of multiple entries because theoretically, both copies could have a mutation and I'm not sure how that would be annotated (e.g. could have some that are "want 123; want 456; other"). If you can get a `purrr` statement to work, perhaps a `paste` at the end could work well.

Sample data:

```
d = tribble(
  ~id, ~to_sep,                 ~other_info,
  1,   "want 543;discard;toss", "important",
  2,   "nothing;worth;keeping", "stuff",
  3,   "want 129",              "is", 
  4,   "meh;want 657",          "here too" 
)
```

My inelegant solution:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(
    test = str_split(to_sep, ";")
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    test2 = list(case_when(
      any(str_detect(test, "want")) ~ str_subset(test, "want"),
      TRUE ~ "NA"
    ))
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  unnest(test2, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

I've also considered splitting, unnesting, filtering, grouping, pasting, and calling distinct(., .keep_all=TRUE) [there are other columns I'd need to keep, thus not summarize]. But this is no prettier/easier.

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     id to_sep                other_info test      test2    final
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      <list>    <chr>    <chr>
1     1 want 543;discard;toss important  <chr [3]> want 543 543  
2     2 nothing;worth;keeping stuff      <chr [3]> NA       NA   
3     3 want 129              is         <chr [1]> want 129 129  
4     4 meh;want 657          here too   <chr [2]> want 657 657
```

...which I can use and get rid of the intermediate columns. But, as I said, this feels like I ought to be able to do it in one `purrr::map` step perhaps with or without a case_when to deal with the `NA`s. Thoughts and suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I think it'll be more straightforward (and I expect more performant) to use `tidyr::separate_rows` to get each entry its own row, then use vectorized filter + mutate and a fast join.

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(d, d %>%
                separate_rows(to_sep, sep = ";") %>%
                filter(str_detect(to_sep, "want")) %>%
                mutate(final = parse_number(to_sep)) %>% 
                select(id, test2 = to_sep, final),
          by = "id")
```

Result

```
    id to_sep                other_info test2    final
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 want 543;discard;toss important  want 543   543
2     2 nothing;worth;keeping stuff      NA          NA
3     3 want 129              is         want 129   129
4     4 meh;want 657          here too   want 657   657
```

If you feed it data with multiple matches, it outputs separate rows for each match:

```
d <- tribble(
  ~id, ~to_sep,                 ~other_info,
  1,   "want 543;want 123;toss", "important",  # THIS ROW CHANGED
  2,   "nothing;worth;keeping", "stuff",
  3,   "want 129",              "is", 
  4,   "meh;want 657",          "here too" )
```

Result

```
     id to_sep                 other_info test2    final
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 want 543;want 123;toss important  want 543   543
2     1 want 543;want 123;toss important  want 123   123
3     2 nothing;worth;keeping  stuff      NA          NA
4     3 want 129               is         want 129   129
5     4 meh;want 657           here too   want 657   657
```

Comment: Dear Jon I borrowed your data set for testing, Thanks indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ****base R**** solution you could use for any number of matches in each row:

```
d$test <- regmatches(d$to_sep, gregexpr("want\\s\\d+", d$to_sep, perl = TRUE))
d$test <- sapply(d$test, \(x) paste(unlist(x), sep = ", "))
d$final <- gsub("[^0-9 ]", "", d$test)
d

  id                to_sep other_info     test final
1  1 want 543;discard;toss  important want 543   543
2  2 nothing;worth;keeping      stuff              0
3  3              want 129         is want 129   129
4  4          meh;want 657   here too want 657   657
```

With @Jon Spring's data set (Thanks for providing):

```
  id                 to_sep other_info               test     final
1  1 want 543;want 123;toss  important want 543, want 123  543  123
2  2  nothing;worth;keeping      stuff                            0
3  3               want 129         is           want 129       129
4  4           meh;want 657   here too           want 657       657
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `str_extract_all` to extract all the `'want'` + number from `to_sep` and extract the number from it using `str_extract`.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  mutate(test2 = str_extract_all(to_sep, 'want \\d+'), 
         final = map(test2, str_extract, '\\d+'), 
         test2 = map_chr(test2, toString))

#     id to_sep                other_info test2      final    
#  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>      <list>   
#1     1 want 543;discard;toss important  "want 543" <chr [1]>
#2     2 nothing;worth;keeping stuff      ""         <chr [0]>
#3     3 want 129              is         "want 129" <chr [1]>
#4     4 meh;want 657          here too   "want 657" <chr [1]>
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_remove` and `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d %>% 
   mutate(test2 = str_extract(to_sep, "want\\s+\\d+"), 
         final = trimws(str_remove_all(to_sep, "[^0-9;]+"), whitespace = ";"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id to_sep                 other_info test2    final    
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 want 543;want 123;toss important  want 543 "543;123"
2     2 nothing;worth;keeping  stuff      <NA>     ""       
3     3 want 129               is         want 129 "129"    
4     4 meh;want 657           here too   want 657 "657"
```